# Pushing to GitHub using a different user over https

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push a new repo to Github on a machine that isn't mine. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
user (master) sample_app $ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to ME/sampleapp.git denied to NOTMYUSERNAME.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ME/sampleapp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Why isn't it prompting me for my username and password? It is over https?

edit:
I've tried editing the global gitconfig file to remove the old username. But there seems to be no mention of 'NOTMYUSERNAME' in there.

Comment: Is there a `[credential]` section in your `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: Do you have access to this repo? and just try once by using simple git push origin master without using '-u'.

Comment: Ryan - after running subl ~/.gitconfig from within the local repo folder:

[color]
 ui = auto
[core]
 editor = subl -n -w
[push]
 default = upstream
[merg]
 conflictstyle = diff3
[log]
 date = local
[filter "lfs"]
 clean = git-lfs clean %f
 smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
 required = true

Comment: Aparna - I have the username/password. Otherwise it is a public repo.

Comment: Okay, it might be the global config variable issue so you can give a try to resolve by uisng @xero answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not having any luck with @xero's answer either

Answer (score 2):

**Have you setup your git credentials for this repo?**

Run `git config -l` and make sure your *user.name* and *user.email* are correctly set.

If not, set them locally for just this repo:

`git config user.name "Your Name"`

`git config user.email "Your email"`

You can also pass these arguments via the command line

`git -c "user.name=Your Name" -c "user.email=Your email" commit ...`

**Have you checked your remotes?**

Calling: `git remote -v` should show you something like:

`origin  https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git (fetch)`

`origin  https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git (push)`

If all looks correct, `git push <remote> <branch>` should prompt you for your username and password.

Comment: user (master) sample_app $ git config -l
color.ui=auto
core.editor=subl -n -w
push.default=upstream
merg.conflictstyle=diff3
log.date=local
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/MYGITPROFILE/sampleapp.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: user (master) sample_app $ git config user.name "My Name"

user (master) sample_app $ git config user.email "myemail@gmail.com"

user (master) sample_app $ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/MYGITPROFILE/sampleapp.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/MYGITPROFILE/sampleapp.git (push)
user (master) sample_app $ git push origin master
remote: Permission to MYGITPROFILE/sampleapp.git denied to NOTME.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MYGITPROFILE/sampleapp.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 1):

After contacting support at GitHub, I found my computer was caching incorrect credentials. This is specific to Mac. Instructions to clear the cache can be found here:

https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/